# Let $A\in\operatorname{M}_n(F)$ be a matrix, how to prove $\bigcap_{X\in C(A)}C(X)=F[A]=\frac{F[x]}{(m_A(x))}$

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, central-simple-algebras

I asked the following question on Math Stack Exchange, but no people reply.  I know MO is more professional and it is for mathematicians to discuss research problems. Maybe this question is unsuitable for here. I truly appreciated if someone who could give me an explanation.

Let $A\in\operatorname{M}_n(F)$. How to prove the following identity.
  $$\bigcap_{X\in C(A)}C(X)=F[A]=\frac{F[x]}{(m_A(x))}.$$
  Here $m_A(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $C(A)$ is the centralizer of $A$ and $C(X)$ is the centralizer of $X$.
  We can view $F^n$ as an $F[x]$-module via $A$, which is well known, denote this module  by $F^n_A$, we have
  $$C(A)=\operatorname{End}_{F[x]}(F^n_A,F^n_A)$$
  Since
  $$F^n_A\simeq\bigoplus_{i=1}^t\frac{F[x]}{(d_i(x))},\quad d_1\mid d_2\mid\cdots\mid d_t\quad\text{(invariant factors)}.$$
  We have
  $$C(A)=\bigoplus_{i}\bigoplus_{j}\operatorname{Hom}_{F[x]}
  \left(\frac{F[x]}{(d_i(x))},\frac{F[x]}{(d_j(x))}\right)
  \simeq\bigoplus_{i=1}^{t}\left(\frac{F[x]}{(d_i(x))}\right)^{2(t-i)+1}.$$
  For $X\in C(A)$, what is $C(X)$? Can we write the structure of $C(X)$ explicitly(using the above isomorphism)?

I saw one proof of this result, but the proof is over algebraic closed field and they use Jordan canonical form. Could anyone explain this for me and give a purely algebraic proof. Use matrix method or the module structrue, but must be on the ground field $F$. Thanks in advance.

By the way, are there any relations between this and the double centralizer theorem of central simple algebra?

Comment: I saw the Doulbe Centralizer Theorem on Milne's lecture notes on Class Field Theory(chapter four), it says that:If $A$ is a $F$-algebra and $V$ a faithful semisimple $A$-module. Then $C(C(A))=A$(centralizers taken in $\operatorname{End}_F(V)$). Here if we let $V=F^n$, then $V$ is not a semisimple $A$-module in general. Could we use double centralizer theorem here? I am not sure. Maybe my understanding is wrong. Could you say more about it?

Comment: I don't easily see how one can deduce the general case from the double centralizer theorem. However, if you know the proof over an algebraically closed field, you can deduce it over $F$. (Take an algebraic closure $F \subset \overline{F}$, and remark that $\overline F[A]\cap M_n(F)= F[A]$.)

Comment: I wanted to edit the previous comments, but it was not possible, so I (stupidly) erased it. You are right: $V$ is semi-simple iff $m_A$ has no square factors, so the double centralizer theorem applies only in this situation.

Comment: Nothing, thank you all the same for your comments.

Comment: @Oblomov. You are right. We can deduce it from algebraically closed field, according to your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the Frobenius normal form, see e.g. Theorem 39.3 in Prasolov's book *Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra*. They same argument appears in [Lagerstrom's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1945-08386-4). As the identity holds without any semisimplicity assumption on $A$, it is conceivable that there is a cleaner proof too. But I do not see one.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Lagerstrom's proof is not long. My version: reduce to primary case, take a cyclic decomposition $V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_r$ where $A$ has minimum polynomial $f^{a_i}$ on $V_i$ with $a_1 \ge \ldots \ge a_r$. Let $B \in \bigcap_{C \in \mathrm{Cent}(A)} \mathrm{Cent}(C)$. There exists $C$ commuting with $A$ such that $C$ is the identity on $V_1$ and kills $V_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_r$, so $B(V_1) = V_1$. Let $v_i$ generate $V_i$. Then $B$ is determined by $B(v_1) \in V_1$, since for each $i$ there is $D_i$ commuting with $A$ such that $D(v_1) = v_i$. If $Q(A)v_1 = B(v_1)$ then $B = Q(A)$.